# Chain select - jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, select, chain

I have two select boxes. 
The one contains my exposure type, the second my click rate. Is it possible to do, so you first have to select your exposure type, and when you do that, it will take the click rates to the selected exposure type, and show them in the 2nd select box.

I have searched the net, but couldn't find the thing I really was looking for.

Comment: Yes it is possible and has been illustrated lot of times/places. Check this link: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

if you're updating the second list from database, you have to send ajax request to a server to get the appropriate click rates. if you work locally though, you can add new options directly from javascript:

```
var clickRates = $('<option value="1">value1</option>
                     <option value="2">value2</option>');

$("#myClickRates").append(clickRates);
```